# Better idea for how to update a string for a hangman game

Tags: python-2.x

I'm attempting to make a hangman game in python 2, and I believe the way I am trying to store the information that the user knows about the word (for example, if they've guessed "v" and "a" and the letter was eggplant, the 'information' I'm referring to is the "-----a--" that the user would see). So, my question is as follows: What is the more efficient way that I can store a mutable variable that will be easily updatable like how I want it to be?

```
secret_word = 'tracy'
dashes = ""

def get_guess():
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess: ")
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Your guess must be exactly one character!"
        elif not guess.islower():
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        else:
            break
    return guess

def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    for letter in secret_word:
        if letter == guess:
            dashes += guess
        else:
            dashes += "-"
    return dashes


while True:
    if guess in secret_word:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
        dashes = update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, get_guess())
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
```

The part that would need the update is most likely the `update_dashes` function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store the game state in a string of the form `--a--`, you might consider using a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Each entry in the list could represent a letter and its status. In the example below, a list of [boolean values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) is used to store whether or not each letter in the secret word has been revealed.

```py
secret_word = 'tracy'
revealed_letters = [False] * len(secret_word)  # all letters start off as not revealed

def make_guess(guessed_letter):
    any_letter_revealed = False
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        secret_letter = secret_word[i]
        if secret_letter == guessed_letter:
            any_letter_revealed = True
            revealed_letters[i] = True
    return any_letter_revealed


def get_hidden_word():
    return ''.join([secret_word[i] if revealed_letters[i] else '-' for i in range(len(secret_word))])


while True:
    print(get_hidden_word())
    guess = raw_input("Guess a letter: ")
    if make_guess(guess):
        print("That letter is in the secret word!")
    else:
        print("That letter is not in the secret word.")
    if all(revealed_letters):
        print("You win! The secret word was:")
        print(secret_word)
        break
```

Comment: what does [False] mean?

on top of that, thank you so much! this code works perfectly, and doesn't have any buggy double questioning that the first code had. this was extremely helpful, thank you

Comment: False is a boolean value. The square brackets around False indicate that it is in a list. This list contains one item, which is False. By multiplying this one-item list by the length of the word (which we do in line 2), we get a list that has as many Falses in it as there are letters in the word (i.e. [False, False, False, False, False]). We then use this list to maintain the state of each letter.